# How to check if slider of jquery.ui.touch-punch is touched?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using http://touchpunch.furf.com/ to enable touch on mobile sliders ans that works perfectly fine. Just that I want to be able to display slider's current value as the slider is touched.

```
LIBARY
<!--slider event starts-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="../scripts/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script>$('#slider_small').draggable();</script>
<!--slider event ends-->
```

On desktop, I use mousemove but on mobile devises I've no idea what to use:

```
$("#slider").mousemove( function(e){
        $("#valBox").html($(this).val());
});
```

I've tried, on "tap", "ontouchstart", dragable,"mousedown". Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#slider_small").bind("touchmove", function() { 

        $("#valBox_small").html($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try virtual mouse events provided by jQuery.

Try below code

```
$( document ).on( "vmousedown", "#slider_small", function() {
   $("#valBox_small").html($(this).val());
});
```

see the documentation [here](https://api.jquerymobile.com/vmousedown/)